# Extrair nomes formatados com cores especificas em diferentes posições

Tags: microsoft-excel

Tenho nomes e eles tem cores correspondentes ao próprio nome da cor. Pretendo extrair esses nomes referente as cores que eu desejar. O problema é que eles estão em posições diferentes, por exemplo: como eu faço para extrair os caracteres em "Azul"??[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

```
EXT.TEXTO(A40;LOCALIZAR("AZUL";A40);4)
```

Comment: Foi útil. O problema são os espaços, que no caso eu teria que alterar a fórmula cada vez quando for uma palavra que tiver no meio de outras e também tem a quantidade de caracteres a ser exibida, pois para cada espaço especifico antes da palavra eu teria que alterar a fórmula. Eu já fiz uma fórmula condicional para respectivos espaços diferentes e caracteres. Porém é bem trabalhoso e extenso, dependendo do tamanho da lista de palavras